# Getter property not returning updated value in Console.log

Tags: javascript

I am a bit stuck with the below scenario.
I am currently reading *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide* and came with below code under the Accessor properties.

```
function inherit(p) {
    if (p == null) throw TypeError();

    if (Object.create) {
        return Object.create(p);
    }

    var t = typeof p;
    if (t !== 'Object' && t !== 'function') throw TypeError();

    function f() {};
    f.prototype = p;
    return new f();
};
```

The above is a simple code that sets the prototype of the newly created Object.
The below is a simple code, in which when `next` is called, is supposed to return a value greater than 55, i.e. 56

```
var serialNum = {
    $n: 0,

    get next() {
        return this['$n']++;
    },

    set next(n) {
        if (n >= this.$n) {
            this.$n = n;
        } else {
            throw 'serial number can only be set to a larger value';
        }
    }
};

var genSerialNum = inherit(serialNum);
genSerialNum.$n = 55;
console.log(genSerialNum.next);
```

So when I set `$n` of `genSerialNum` Object it creates a `$n` property of `genSerialNum` and on calling the getter property `next`, it increments 55 to 56(as this is what I can see from the scope Variable of the chrome dev tools), but on printing in console it displays 55. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about it:

```
> i = 0
0
> i++
0
> i
1
```

See [JavaScript Increment operator (++ )](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/operators/arithmetic-special-operators.php)

Comment: Thanks Speransky, I completely forgot about this.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you're seeing the old value returned because you're using the postfix operator.

This confusion is (part of) the reason why Douglas Crockford recommends using the `+=` operator instead of pre/post --/++ in *JavaScript the Good Parts*.

```
get next(){
    return this['$n'] += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

since you have used `this['$n']++`(postfix operator) the value of `$n` is incremented after the value is returned to the caller, if you want to print 56 then use `++this['$n']`(prefix operator)

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Q8m8j/)

Comment: Thanks Arun, I guess I need to revisit some concepts here.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to say what @Speransky is saying is that this problem has nothing to do with getters and setters, but rather the way that the `++` operator works. To put it another way:

```
var i = 0; 

console.log(i); // 0
console.log(i++); // 0
console.log(i); // 1
```

`i++` will return the original value of `i` and then will increment it.